# Assigning latest file name to variable in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ls, do-loops

I'm trying to assign unique and latest file name into a variable. then variable will be called in loop for further processing.But i'm getting variable filename is not getting resolved as expected. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Problem statement : In the below given case, the files 1234_99999999_20190701141516.txt and  1234_88888888_20190701154444.txt has to be picked for insert through the function 'Inserttable'

Sample file :

```
1234_99999999_20190701141516.txt
1234_88888888_20190701144446.txt
1234_88888888_20190701154444.txt
```

sample data:

```
1234_99999999_20190701141516.txt :9999999|1|IN|chris|20 street 1|xxxxxx|yyyyy|wwwww
1234_88888888_20190701154444.txt :8888888|1|IN|David|10 street 2|zzzzzz|cccccc|eeeeee
```

Code :

```
ls ????_?????????_*.txt | cut -f2 -d'_' |uniq > filename.txt
while read BR_NBR
do
FILENAME= `ls *${BR_NBR}* | sort -r | head -1`
echo ${FILENAME}
MEM_NBR=`awk -F "|" '{ print $1 }' ${FILENAME}`
CARDHOLDER_NBR=`awk -F "|" '{ print $2 }' ${FILENAME}`
CNTRY_CODE=`awk -F "|" '{ print $3 }' ${FILENAME}`
echo  $MEM_NBR
echo $CARD_NBR
echo $CNTRY_CODE
Inserttable
done < filename.txt
```

my issue : I'm trying to resolve file name into 'FILENAME'

Comment: does `ls *${BR_NBR}*` output anything? Plus, could you try removing the spaces around `=` sign in shell code?

Comment: Do not use backticks, prefer `$(..)`. Prefer to use lowercase variables, uppercase are used for exported variables. Use shellcheck to check your script.

Comment: ```FILENAME= `ls``` - you can't have a space after the `=`. Copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it tells you about, update your question with the fixed code (indented legibly this time) and then let us know if you still have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i have removed the space which has resolved the issue.

Comment: @NikO'Lai yes ls *${BR_NBR}* it gave an output